# Facebook batch size

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to know is there are some limits when using Facebook API for web applications. I am interested especially in batch size limit (FacebookClient.Batch method) - how many params can I safely execute at once?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Limits
>
> We currently limit the number of batch requests to 50.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

[edit: the batch limit was raised from 20 to 50 since this was first posted]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that - I didn't notice. I have following code: var batch = facebookClient.Batch(new FacebookBatchParameter(HttpMethod.Delete, facebookObjectIds[0]), new FacebookBatchParameter(HttpMethod.Delete, facebookObjectIds[1])); <- there is not way I can delete more than 20 objects at once, right?

Comment: from what i am reading, i do not see a way to batch an array for delete.  If i find a method i will post a new answer.